# doubt with direction angles

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors, 3d

Is it possible for a 3D vector to be drawn with the direction angles of $\alpha=45^\circ$ and $\beta=45^\circ$ ? if yes what is measure of $\gamma^\circ$?

I calculated $\cos^2(45^\circ )+\cos^2(45^\circ )+\cos^2(\gamma) = 1$
so $\gamma= \pi/2$.
I am right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: is it possible to draw if alpha=beta=40 and alpha=beta=50? by the same calculations?

Comment: for alpha=beta=40 i cannot calculated gamma. why so? what is the physical intepretation of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are angles of the 3D vector against the x, y and z axis of the coordinate system. That does not mean that they are independent variables for defining a 3D vector in the space. For example, you cannot have a 3D vector that has 90 degree to all the 3 axes and you cannot have a 3D vector that has 0 degree to any 2 axes either. For any given angle (or angles), if you cannot find a solution for other angle(s), it simply means such a 3D vector does not exist.